# how do I create a unique id in java with information that has been inputted by the user?

Tags: java, oop, uuid

I need the program to create a unique ID for tasks, people, etc. I am having trouble, however with getting it to create a unique id with information provided by the user in the form of an input.

I have not tried yet, but I simply can't remember how. I have seen other people create unique IDs using the GUID function/import, but I haven't seen people create an id based on information provided by the user/ for example the ID will need to be made of the first 3 letters of the user's name, the last 3 digits of the user's birthday as well as the number of hours they have worked.

Comment: I mean, you could do that but it's unlikely to be as distributed as the existing UUID implementation. Of course, you could use an existing UUID implementation and then prepend and append whatever you want.

Comment: *"for example the ID will need to be made of the first 3 letters of the user's name, the last 3 digits of the user's birthday as well as the number of hours they have worked"* - And have you tried using those values to produce this ID?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  It sounds like you know what you want to do, it's not clear what's stopping you from doing it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Show an example of how you would like the UUID to look like.

Answer (score 0):

According to the pattern you provided:

- 3 first letters of the name: you can use the username.substring(0,2) function;
- The last 3 digits of the user's birthday, assuming it is 31/12/1999 you mean the year.

If it is string, the same substring function will suffice in the range that you see.
If it is date you will have to use the SimpleDateFormat class and instantiate a pattern of how to get the data Ex: 'SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); sdf.format(tu_date);'
This code may give you an exception so lock it in a try/catch.

Comment: A good [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) would make your post look good.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation, I will improve. I'm also new to stackoverflow and I don't handle English very well.

Comment: Take it easy, there are lots of people that are non-native English speakers (I am one of them). Just try to keep learning and improving things. Then you will see that you had developed your skills.